# checking if multiple checkboxes are checked using custom attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have multiple groups of checkboxes like these:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="correction_check" product_id="3" defect_col="Qty">
<input type="checkbox" class="correction_check" product_id="3" defect_col="Exp">
<input type="checkbox" class="correction_check" product_id="3" defect_col="Bat">

<input type="checkbox" class="correction_check" product_id="4" defect_col="Qty">
<input type="checkbox" class="correction_check" product_id="4" defect_col="Bat">
```

A group of checkboxes is differentiated by `product_id`.

Can I do something like this?

```
$('.correction_check').click(function(){
    //check if all other check boxes having same product_id as $(this) are checked and do some action
});
```

Comment: using the 'name' attribute to group various inputs is more semantic

Comment: @Mike86 Not for checboxes, this would prevent the sending of the different inputs in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if all other checkboxes with same `product_id` are checked like this :

```
$('.correction_check').click(function(){
    var otherAreChecked = $('.correction_check[product_id='+$(this).attr('product_id')+']')
       .not(this).not(':checked').length===0;
    // do action
});
```

The idea is to count the ones that are not checked : this count should be 0.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/OyivOHu/1/)

Note that if you want to know if all check boxes with same product id are checked (not just the "other" ones), you just have to remove `.not(this)` from my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".correction_check").change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("product_id");
    $(".correction_check[product_id='"+id+"']:checked").each(function(){
        //do action
    });
});
```